# Memory leak when using freetype library

Tags: c++, opengl, freetype2

In the following code snippet, I am leaking 52 bytes of memory for every iteration of the for loop, but after several hours I am unable to determine why =/

Any help will be appreciated.

```
    for(unsigned char i=0; i<128; ++i)
    {
        ttf.loadGlyph(i);
        FT_Glyph glyph;
        FT_Get_Glyph(ttf.ftFace_->glyph, &glyph);
        FT_Glyph_To_Bitmap( &glyph, ft_render_mode_normal, 0, 1 );
        FT_BitmapGlyph bitmap_glyph = (FT_BitmapGlyph)glyph;
        FT_Bitmap& bitmap = bitmap_glyph->bitmap;

        int width = nextPowerOf2(bitmap.width);
        int height = nextPowerOf2(bitmap.rows);
        GLubyte* expanded_data = new GLubyte[ 2 * width * height]; // Allocate Memory For The Texture Data.

        for(int j=0; j <height;j++) {
            for(int i=0; i < width; i++){
                expanded_data[2*(i+j*width)]= expanded_data[2*(i+j*width)+1] =
                    (i>=bitmap.width || j>=bitmap.rows) ?
                    0 : bitmap.buffer[i + bitmap.width*j];
            }
        }
        glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, fontData_.pTextures_[i]);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
        glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, expanded_data );

        delete [] expanded_data;

        glNewList(fontData_.fontBase_+i, GL_COMPILE);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, fontData_.pTextures_[i]);
        glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef( (GLfloat)bitmap_glyph->left, 0.0f, 0.0f );
        glTranslatef(0.0f, (GLfloat)bitmap_glyph->top-bitmap.rows, 0.0f);

        float   x=(float)bitmap.width / (float)width,
            y=(float)bitmap.rows / (float)height;

        glBegin(GL_QUADS);

        glTexCoord2d(0,0); glVertex3f( 0, 0, 1 );                       //Bottom-left vertex (corner) 
        glTexCoord2d(0,y); glVertex3f( 0, (GLfloat)bitmap.rows, 1 );    // top left vertex
        glTexCoord2d(x,y); glVertex3f( (GLfloat)bitmap.width, (GLfloat)bitmap.rows, 1 ); // top right vertex
        glTexCoord2d(x,0); glVertex3f( (GLfloat)bitmap.width, 0, 1 );   // bottom right

        glEnd();
        glPopMatrix();
        glTranslatef( (GLfloat)( ttf.ftFace_->glyph->advance.x >> 6 ), 0, 0);
        glEndList();
    }
```

Comment: I might be completely off, but this looks suspicious: `glNewList(fontData_.fontBase_+i, GL_COMPILE);` The first parameter should be a unique number you get from `glGenLists()`, but from this code it is not obvious if you're doing that.

Comment: It is kind of impossible to determine the reason of the leak. Read the docu very good. Probably some functions you are using allocates something that you aren't freeing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [the docs](http://www.freetype.org/freetype2/docs/reference/ft2-glyph_management.html#FT_Get_Glyph):

> FT_Get_Glyph
>
> A function used to extract a glyph image from a slot. **Note that the
>   created FT_Glyph object must be released with FT_Done_Glyph.**